# Autofac fails to resolve enumerable of typed HttpClients

Tags: autofac, httpclientfactory

I have a number of services which require usage of typed HttpClient from HttpClientFactory. 
Though I can resolve one service I can't resolve IEnumerable of this services.

```
interface IMyHttpClient
{
}

class MyHttpClient: IMyHttpClient
{
    public MyHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddHttpClient()
                .AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Exception goes away when remove this line
        builder.RegisterType<MyHttpClient>().As<IMyHttpClient>();
        builder.Populate(services);
        var provider = builder.Build();

        // ============== This works
        // provider.Resolve<IMyHttpClient>();

        // ============== This throws exception
        provider.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyHttpClient>>();
    }
}
```

Constructor will be called once and than exception is thrown:

```
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ConsoleApp2.MyHttpClient' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient client' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient)'.

```

The issue is that AddHttpClient adds it's own registration of IMyHttpClient. But I do want to register using Autofac only! Is there a way to use typed clients but still stay with Autofac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception explains that Autofac can't resolve parameter 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient client'. I suppose this is because such type wasn't registered in your container for second resgistration of `IMyHttpClient`. To save an advantages of `HttpClientFactory` you can register excplicit constructor parameter for example like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddHttpClient();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // exclicit resolving client for constructor
    builder.RegisterType<MyHttpClient>().As<IMyHttpClient>().WithParameter(
        (p, ctx) => p.ParameterType == typeof(HttpClient), 
        (p, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient());

    builder.Populate(services);
    var provider = builder.Build();

    // ============== This works
    provider.Resolve<IMyHttpClient>();

    // ============== This works too
    provider.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyHttpClient>>();
}
```

In this example `Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyHttpClient>>` return enumeration with single `IMyHttpClient`, that is initialized with `HttpClient` from core HttpClientFactory.

UPD: the post was updated by @norekhov comment

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought of. Instead of registering multiple clients in ServiceCollection domain I will put there only .AddHttpClient and than resolve params directly inside Autofac registrations. Than `services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>();` can be replaced with `services.AddHttpClient();` just for basic registrations.

Comment: If you need just resolve `HttpClient` instances using core HttpClientFactory, yes, it will work for you.

Comment: Updated answer to prevent duplicated registration of `IMyHttpClient`.