# Asp.Net Core 3.0 use HttpClientFactory with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

I have a quite default Asp.Net Core 3.0 RestAPI application. For some services inside I would like to use Asp.Net Core's builtin HttpClientFactory.

So I have these in my Startup.cs in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHttpClient<IService1, Service1>(client =>
{
     client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
});
services.AddHttpClient<IService2, Service2>(client =>
{
     client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
});
```

And one of my Service constructor seems like this:

```
protected Service1(HttpClient client)
{
    this.client = client;
}
```

In my Startup.cs I have DI config section for Autofac:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<Service1>().As<IService1>();
    builder.RegisterType<Service2>().As<IService2>();
}
```

My problem, this is not working, because of Autofac doesn't know about MS DI base HttpClientFactory settings in ConfigureServices. What should I configure to use Asp.Net Core HttpClientFactory with Autofac?

I also tried this advice: [Autofac fails to resolve enumerable of typed HttpClients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291150/autofac-fails-to-resolve-enumerable-of-typed-httpclients)

Comment: Register the services with default DI and see if they transfer over to autofac

Comment: Unfortunatelly my services use the same interface, this is why I'm using Autofac for keyed resolvation of services with same interface. Above that was only some "pseudo" example code.

Answer (score 0):

I successed to solve this with named configs.

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient("sampleClient", client =>
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
});
```

In Service.cs constructor

```
public Service(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("sampleClient");
}
```